# Regular expression in bash not working in conditional construct in Bash with operator '=~'

Tags: bash, sh

The regular expression I have put into the conditional construct (with the =~ operator) would not return the value as I had expected, but when I assign them into two variables it worked. Wondering if I had done something wrong.

Version 1 (this one worked)

```sh
a=30
b='^[0-9]+$' #pattern looking for a number
[[ $a =~ $b ]]
echo $?

#result is 0, as expected
```

Version 2 (this one doesn't work but I thought it is identical)

```sh
[[ 30 =~ '^[0-9]+$' ]]
echo $?

#result is 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't quote the regular expression:

```
[[ 30 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]
echo $?
```

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.

So if you quote the entire pattern, it's treated as a fixed string match rather than a regular expression.

Comment: Also, I recommend putting the pattern in a variable and using the unquoted variable in the match expression: `pattern='^[0-9]+$'` and `[[ 30 =~ $pattern ]]` - this allows you to include characters such as whitespace in the pattern.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson The question already shows how to do it using a variable, he was just wondering why it didn't work with a literal.

Comment: Back to remedial reading for me! But it's useful to point out why a variable _should_ be used and not a literal pattern.